# Adding numeric navigation to Custom Post Type with no truncating

Tags: custom-post-types, navigation

I am building a custom WordPress site for an artist with some Custom Post Types set up in it to display his artworks (I set up several Custom Post Types such as Artwork-painting, Artwork-sculpture etc).

On each Custom Post Types post page, I want to put navigation buttons that is more complete than just Previous and Next button - I want to show links to all the posts within that Custom Post Types. For example, there are 50 posts in the artworks-sculpture Custom Post Types. The navigation will have the links to all the posts -  1 to 50  ( 1 2 3 until 50 ). I don't want hiding/truncating any numbers. ( I see some sites condense the numeric pagination with ellipsis, I don't want that).

How can I do that?

Comment: what is actually the question? what code have you actually tried?

Comment: There is `show_all` argument in the [paginate_links()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) function.